# How to compare string with float? in Objective C

Tags: objective-c, string, floating-point, comparison

How would you? I'm having problems. Thanks.

I'm currently using

```
if (myString == myfloat) {
// do something but this won't work
}
```

OR

```
if ([myString == myFloat]) {
// do something but this won't work
}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

The `==` operator only makes sense when the two types are compatible, which is not the case between strings and floats. One side must be explicitly converted to the other.

You may convert the NSString into a float:

```
if ([myString floatValue] == myFloat) {
  // Note: Use "fabs(a - b) < epsilon" to avoid inequality due to precision lost.
```

or convert the float into an NSString (very unusual):

```
if ([myString isEqualToString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%g", myFloat]]) {
  // Note: make sure the string is encoded as "%g" as well.
```